# Map Unicode characters to similar EBCDIC 1047 characters automatically

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, ebcdic, non-unicode

I'm trying to encode a string that has characters not supported by the target encoding ([CP 1047](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_1047)).

Is there a standard/common/easy way of mapping those characters to a cp1047 equivalent?

For example, the text has a fancy double quote character (`”`) and I want to convert it to the straight double quote (`"`).

Obviously I could just do the replace in my code, but is their a better way?  Is there an open source tool, or API out there that I don't know about?

Comment: That vast majority of Unicode characters don't _have_ CP1047 equivalents.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808967/replacing-unicode-punctuation-with-ascii-approximations points to this web page with a decent looking conversion table http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/current/docs/designDoc/UDF/unicode/DefaultTables/symbolTable.html

Comment: It is far easier, and infinitely preferable, to upgrade your legacy encodings to Unicode than to downgrade Unicode into the musty old rotting boxes of legacy encodings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to encode Unicode characters in EBCDIC (CP 1047), then (apparently) there's [UTF-EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-EBCDIC) (though I don't know of any existing tools that can convert to that).

Alternatively, I would look into using the non-standard form of [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) or  [XML/HTML encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). Either one of these two encodings would probably have existing tools for encoding (such as Commons Lang [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)).

Finally, if you just want to 'map' extended characters into the CP 1047 space then I guess you're left with scanning the source string character by character and building the result string from a `Map<Char, Char>` (or `Map<Char, String>`), so long as you know beforehand all the extended characters you have to deal with and their desired equivalents/replacements.