# Java: how to replace tricky/fancy dash and quotes with regular dash and quotes

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-8, replace, ascii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replacing unicode punctuation with ASCII approximations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808967/replacing-unicode-punctuation-with-ascii-approximations)

I think I can totally blame Microsoft for this, but I have some string stored in my database and they have these dashes and quotes that aren't the normal dashes and quotes.  I think they're trying to be smart or something...

It is displaying on the page just fine, but I need to send it as ASCII to a different program.

I have looked at this question [Convert Unicode to ASCII without changing the string length (in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096667/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-changing-the-string-length-in-java), and specifically @Denis Tulskiy answer, but it turns the fancy dashes into question marks instead of normal dashes.  How do I modify it to work on those few characters?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace these fancy characters with ones you find more appropriate and which have a representation in ASCII. Finally call `String.getBytes("ASCII")` to get the desired encoding.