# Decoding and Encoding in Python

Tags: python

I have some text that I am trying to decode and encode in Python

```
import html.parser

original_tweet = "I luv my &lt;3 iphone &amp; you’re awsm 
                 apple.DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  
                 http://www.apple.com"
tweet = original_tweet.decode("utf8").encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

I have entered the original tweet on one line in Spyder (Python 3.6)

I get the following message

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Is there an alternative way to rewrite this code for Python 3.6?

Comment: You seem to be confused what a string in Python represents and what encoding or decoding does. Encoding turns a string into bytes, decoding the opposite. In that light, your call doesn't make sense and hence it also fails.

Comment: This is the website I am following and am unable to understand what is going on: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2014/11/text-data-cleaning-steps-python/

Comment: You can not use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) and [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to handle the HTML entities `&lt;` and `&amp;` if that’s what you’re trying to do. Look into libs like [Parsing HTML with lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) for that (based on you importing a HTML parser). However, your string `original_tweet` isn’t proper HTML, so you may consider fudging that first…

Comment: @cordelia That website's code does not make any sense. If your `original_tweet` value is a character string already, there's no need to encode or decode it. If it's a byte string (i.e. a `bytes` object), `decode` it once to get a character string.

Comment: I believe that the code on that website was written for Python 2. There, a regular string (without `u` prefix) is a byte sequence, which can be decoded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. This has put me on the right track and prevented me from going round in circles.

Comment: How do I tweak this for  Python 3.6 then? SHould I put a u in front of the original_tweet code?

Comment: @cordelia what are you trying to achieve? Every string in Py3+ is a UTF8 encoded Unicode string already.

Comment: I need to transform the data and change the encoding format.

Comment: @cordelia Change the encoding format to _what_?

Comment: I thinnk ascii is the format

Comment: @cordelia, that’s unlikely to work considering the Unicode emoji 
 in the original string which can not be represented in plain [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/mobile/). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299675/python-script-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ascii) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-in-python) question to convert the UTF8 encoded string `original_tweet` into a plain ASCII string.

Comment: Thank you @Jens but how do I do this in Python 3.6 everything seems to be done in Python 2.7.

Comment: If you can live some data loss then `original_tweet.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii", errors="ignore")` should work. First, [encode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) the string into an array of bytes, then [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) that array and dismiss possible decode errors.

Comment: That seems to work except it does not correct the &lt and &amp the way it is corrected on the website.

Comment: Do you recommend my using a parser on original_tweet and then applying your encode and decode code to that?

Comment: 'code'original_tweet = "I luv my &lt;3 iphone &amp; you’re awsm apple. DisplayIsAwesome, sooo happppppy  http://www.apple.com"

tweet = html.parser.unescape(original_tweet)
print (tweet) 'code'

Comment: How do I avoid losing the 're in the you're ? I have reposted this because I posted it in the Answer section by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3+, your `original_tweet` string is a [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) string containing a [Unicode emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). Because the 65k+ characters in Unicode are a superset of the 256 [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters, you can not simply convert a Unicode string into an ASCII string.

However, if you can live with some data loss (i.e. drop the emoji) then you can try the following (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299675/python-script-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ascii) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors-in-python) related question):

```
original_tweet = "I luv my &lt;3 iphone &amp; you’re awsm ..."

# Convert the original UTF8 encoded string into an array of bytes.
original_tweet_bytes = original_tweet.encode("utf-8")

# Decode that array of bytes into a string containing only ASCII characters;
# pass errors="strict" to find failing character mappings, and I also suggest
# to read up on the option errors="replace".
original_tweet_ascii = original_tweet_bytes.decode("ascii", errors="ignore")
```

Or as a simple one-liner:

```
tweet = original_tweet.encode("utf-8").decode("ascii", errors="ignore")
```

Note that this does *not* convert the [HTML entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) `&lt;` and `&amp;` which you may have to address separately. You can do that using a proper HTML parser (e.g. [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html)), or use a simple [string replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
tweet = tweet.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&amp;", "&")
```

Or as of Python 3.4+ you can use [`html.unescape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) like so:

```
tweet = html.unescape(tweet)
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) on how to handle HTML entities in strings.

**Addendum.** The [Unidecode](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode) package for Python seems to provide useful functionality for this, too, although in its current version it does not handle emojis.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me with this. That truly resolves my query.

Comment: How do I avoid losing the 're for the you're? Apologies for bugging you with this but I just noticed it.

Comment: @cordelia, the `’` character is Unicode character [U+2019](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) and has no direct equivalent in ASCII. What you can do, however, is to use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace all `‘` and `’` with ASCII `'` and the double quotation marks `“` and `”` with ASCI `"`. See also this question: [Replacing unicode punctuation with ASCII approximations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808967/replacing-unicode-punctuation-with-ascii-approximations).

Comment: Thanks for this @Jens